Problems displaying a table next to an image in Python and QT6
I have problems displaying a QTableView next to an image (QLabel / QPixmax) in window size.
The table as well as the image (original size 600 x 400 pixels) are displayed very small, see attached image.
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QLabel, QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])
    
    
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.resize(1200, 700)


        # tabel
        self.table = QTableView()

        data = [
          [4, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [7, 8, 9],
        ]

        self.model =  TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,50)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(1,50)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(2,50)

        # picture
        self.picture = QLabel(self)
        #self.picture.setScaledContents(True)
        #self.picture.setMaximumWidth(600)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('Bilder/no_image_available.jpg')
        # self.pixmap.scaled(self.picture.size(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.picture.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


        # layout
        self.Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.Layout = QSplitter(self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.picture)

        #self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        #self.splitter.addWidget(self.table)
        #self.splitter.addWidget(self.picture)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Output of sample code:

The next step is to use a QSplitter which rescales the size of the image to the remaining width when it is moved.

First of all, QSplitter is a widget, not a layout, so it must be added to a layout manager. You already have one, so create the splitter with a proper name and add it to the layout. Then, I'd put on hold your probably related post due to your last point: QLabel doesn't provide aspect ratio, so you'd need to create new scaled image for every resize. This calls for a subclass, which probably doesn't have to be a QLabel (a part from the actual painting, 90% of QLabel features would be useless). Do some related research as there are already many related posts.

With the comment from @musicamante and further research I was able to solve my problem. In the following code I have added a PushButton that alternately loads two different images when activated.
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])
    
    
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.resize(800, 400)

        # Button
        self.button = QPushButton("toggle Picture")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.load_pictrue)
         
        # tabel
        self.table = QTableView()

        data = [
          [4, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [7, 8, 9],
        ]

        self.model =  TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,50)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(1,50)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(2,50)

        # picture
        self.x = 1
        self.picture = QLabel(self)
        self.load_pictrue()

        # layout with splitter
        self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.table)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.picture)

        self.Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.VLayout.addLayout(self.Layout)

        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

    def load_pictrue(self):
        if self.x % 2:
            pixmap = QPixmap('Bilder/minion.png')
        else:
            pixmap = QPixmap('Bilder/75.08011.595.jpg')

        pixmap.scaled(200, 200, Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.picture.setPixmap(pixmap)     
        self.x += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Note: only use the parent widget argument of constructors when you actually need it. Specifically, doing both QHBoxLayout(self) and QVBoxLayout(self) is pointless (and conceptually wrong), since you're going to add the horizontal layout to the vertical one, and that will be set for the central widget. Similarly: self.picture will be a child of QSplitter, and QSplitter will be a child of self.w. Coincidentally, self.w is the only widget for which using self would have been appropriate (but not necessary in this case). Always use the parent argument with awareness of its purpose.
